# Python - while loop count

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to know the score of "heads" and "tails" in 5 times tossing the coin.
For example, the result should be:
- Heads was 3 times
- Tails was 2 times

```
import random
print("Heads or tails. Let's toss a coin five times.\n")
toss = 1

while toss <= 5:
    coin = ["HEADS", "TAILS"]
    y = random.choice(coin)
    print("Toss number:", toss, "is showing:", y)
    toss = toss + 1
```

Comment: You've already got a variable `toss` which count tosses, why not make 2 more, one counts heads and one counts tails

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be solved within the first few chapters of any decent python tutorial (variables and `if` statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made changes to your code to count the frequency of each coin side (Heads or Tails),

```
import random
print("Heads or tails. Let's toss a coin five times.\n")
toss = 1
counts = {"HEADS": 0, "TAILS": 0}

while toss <= 5:
    coin = ["HEADS", "TAILS"]
    y = random.choice(coin)
    counts[y] += 1
    print("Toss number:", toss, "is showing:", y)
    toss = toss + 1

print("Heads was " + str(counts["HEADS"]) + " times - Tails was " + str(counts["TAILS"]) + " times")
```

Comment: Or, better: `y = random.choice(counts.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

You should have two variables, `head` and `tail`:

```
import random
print("Heads or tails. Let's toss a coin five times.\n")
head = tail = 0

for i in range(5):
    coin = ["HEADS", "TAILS"]
    y = random.choice(coin)
    print("Toss number:", i, "is showing:", y)
    if y == "HEADS":
        head += 1
    elif y == "TAILS":
        tail += 1
```

Or, a better solution would be having a dictionary with keys representing heads and tails, with the value representing the count.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to let `toss` be a list of coin toss results. Starting with an empty list, you could loop until the list contained 5 results and on each toss push a new member into the list. That way you end up with a single data structure that contains all the information you need about the tosses.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables, initialize them to `0`, check the result of the coin toss in a `if` block and add accordingly.

```
heads, tails = 0, 0
if y == "HEADS":
    heads += 1
else:
    tails += 1

return (heads, tails)
```